# Reading list for self study Law students in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, students

I am someone that has studied biochemistry in Newcastle University (BSc), Cambridge University (MPhil) and Nottingham University (PhD) and now I am doing self study of Law. I checked on the Newcastle University reading list for books on law, as the university reading lists have the best books for degree courses. I found "Legals skills" by Finch Fafinski highly recommeded and it is indeed very well written. The course structure for law as decribed in my Legal skills book is remarkably similar to a biochemistry degree. My legal skills book suggests getting hold of other law books on particular topics on law like: criminal law, civil law, imgration law, and so on. At the time I thought I would choose to specialize in Public law and criminal law, so looked up the law books that are popular on the reading list in Newcastle university web site. I got:

(1)Constitutional and Administrative Law (second Edition) by Roger Masterman and Colin Murry

(2)Complete Criminal Law: Text, Cases, and Materials. by Janet Loveless, Mischa Allen, Caroline Derry.

Now I am thinking, that perhaps like my biochemistry degree, that has modules in genetics, biochemistry, pharmacology, cell biology, etc... It is similar in law, that it is not for me to pick a few feilds in law to specialize in but I need to read them all. Indeed the legal skills hand book I had said that there are mandatory subjects in law you need to learn like: criminal law, public law, property law, Equity and trusts and law of the European Union and that these are known as the 'foundation subjects' or 'foundations of legal knowledge'.

Unfortunetly I cannot access the reading list anymore for some odd reason, and would like to know what are the recommended books for the rest of the law degree. Does anyone now what they are? also if it helps I am studing UK law.